# gem install encoding error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass

I recently install ruby in my computer and when I tried to install sass or compass I encountered this error.

```
Home@HOME-PC ~
$ gem -v
2.2.2

Home@HOME-PC ~
$ gem install compass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
U+200F to IBM862 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM862

Home@HOME-PC ~
$ gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
U+200F to IBM862 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM862
```

what caused this error? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in windows some have encountered https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1025

some have reported being able to change the codepage to fix it. From prompt run:

```
chcp 1252
```

then do your gem install again

Comment: coulding fix it from the prompt (chcp not found) but your reference to  https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1025 help me solve the problem. I edited \Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\2.1.0\registry.rb > LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8

Answer (score 2):

@amit-choukroune's comment helped me:

Editing the "C:\Ruby21-x64\lib\ruby\2.1.0\win32\registry.rb" (according to your real install directory)
and change LOCALE constant:
LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8